# Enum value in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an application where I pass enum values to buttons which are on the homescreen. I have four buttons on the homescreen, and when clicked, a button-specific screen should appear.

For that I have to check with the enum values -- and as enum is not supported in java-me, I have them as final static int constants.  On the homescreen I used a FieldChangeListener to implement the buttons. The implementation of the buttons, with enum values, are in another class. How do I check the values with related buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate enums in JavaME using the "type safe enum pattern" proposed by Joshua Bloch in his book "Effective Java Programming Language Guide".

Example:

```
public class ButtonEnum
{

  public static final ButtonEnum TEST = new ButtonEnum("test");
  public static final ButtonEnum HOME = new ButtonEnum("home");
  public static final ButtonEnum EXIT = new ButtonEnum("exit");
  public static final ButtonEnum VIEW2 = new ButtonEnum("view");

  private final String name;

  private ButtonEnum(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Field.setCookie(Object) and Field.getCookie() should do the trick.

Use java.lang.Integer to turn your primitives into objects.

**EDIT**

The field change listener gets a Field.  Call getCookie() on that field, and then you can figure it out, because when you setup the buttons, you called setCookie() with an appropriate object.

Comment: Hi Michel I used setCookie() and getCookie() as u said but it is not working.I forgot to mention that some info regarding issue.If I clicked on any button in fieldChangeListener class I need to push only one screen where the implementation of four buttons is done.In paint method I implemented draw bitmaps to display.How can I determine which button is pressed.

Comment: Yes Michael I used setCookie() and getCookie() for fields but not able to figure it out.i=new Integer(ContentScreen.STAGE_1);invesBtn.setCookie(i);           j=new Integer(ContentScreen.STAGE_2);createBtn.setCookie(j);         here STAGE_1=0,STAGE_2=1 in ContentScreen class.                     In ContentScreen class i implement code for buttons like if  if (currentState == STAGE_1 ) I call a method and for second button also in constructor.But not able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve your problem might be to use the *.setChangeListener()* method on the *ButtonField*. Each button will have a unique listener. Also, there are is enum construct in blackberry JRE. You have to use int constants.

Code:

```
button.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
      public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            // push screen 1...
      }
}});
```